# Node.js convert XML to JSON and return it to Frontend

Tags: json, node.js, xml

I am trying to convert xml data to JSON in order to return it to my Angular app.
I've been able to get data but I'm not sure how to convert and return to Angular.
I am using `xml2js` parser plugin to convert xml.

**node.js**

```
router.get('/courselist',  (req, res, next) => {
request("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml", function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    parser(body, function (err, result) {
       res.json(response);
    });
});
```

After parsing the output is like this:

```
{"gesmes:Envelope": {
    "$": {
        "xmlns:gesmes": "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01",
        "xmlns": "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"
    },
    "gesmes:subject": [
        "Reference rates"
    ],
    "gesmes:Sender": [
        {
            "gesmes:name": [
                "European Central Bank"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Cube": [
        {
            "Cube": [
                {
                    "$": {
                        "time": "2017-09-21"
                    },
                    "Cube": [
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "currency": "USD",
                                "rate": "1.1905"
                            }
                        },
                        ....
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "currency": "JPY",
                                "rate": "133.86"
                            }
                        },

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

**Angular service**

```
getCourseList() {
    return this._http.get('./api/course-list').map(
      (res: Response) => res.json()
    ).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When I call the endpoint in `Postman` I can see parsed output, but in Angular I am getting error as I am not returning JSON object.

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I've been looking around SO for a solution but not been able to find any which would suit me.
Can you please advise what am I doing wrong as I am beginner with Node.js

Comment: Have you inspected the response to make sure it's actually returning JSON?

Comment: It doesn't return JSON, I tried to `JSON.parse(result)` in parser but still no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution I changed parsing to be `response.body` instead of `body` and it formatted XML properly.
Additionally paths in node.js and angular were not same.

```
router.get('/course-list',  (req, res, next) => {
    request("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml", function(error, response, body) {
        var parsedBody;
        var doneParsing = false;
        parser(response.body, function (err, result) {
            parsedBody = result;
            doneParsing = true;
        });
        if (doneParsing === true) {
            response.body = parsedBody;
        }
        res.json(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You angular service is calling `'./api/course-list'` which is not a valid url. And, probably you have configured your server to return `index.html` page for even 404 page. That's why your angular client might be getting `html` page, and throwing the error while parsing it into `

Hope `this._http.get('/api/course-list')` fixes the issue.

Comment: I have proxy setup which replaces .api with proper path. I am definitely calling endpoint properly as I have other endpoints which work. The problem is with data I am sending back to the angular

Comment: Check `Chrome Debugger Console`'s Network tab to see the response you get from backend.  `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` clearly says that the response starts with `<`, and it is possible in case of `html/xml`. Since you have verified the api in Postman, the only possibility left is related to angular-client only.

Comment: I am getting response `Status Code:200 OK`,  content type is not ok `content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: And, check the content as well. It should not be `json`.

Comment: Found solution, part of the problem was the path as in Node.js I had `/courselist` and in angular it was `/course-list`.But I still needed to make more tweaks. Thanks for your help!